# Karma/Jasmine: Pretty printing object comparison

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm currently using the Karma test runner for my Angular project, with the jasmine testing framework. It's working great, but I have one issue: When an object comparison fails, the resulting print into the console is really hard to read, and gets harder the more properties these objects have. Example:

```
Expected spy spy to have been called with [ { currentCareMoment : { ID : 5, Description : 'Late namiddag (16-20)', StartHour : 16, EndHour : 20 }, previousCareMoment : { ID : 4, Description : 'Namiddag (14-16)', StartHour : 14, EndHour : 16 } } ] but actual calls were [ { currentCareMoment : { ID : 6, Description : 'Avond (20-24)', StartHour : 20, EndHour : 24 }, previousCareMoment : { ID : 5, Description : 'Late namiddag (16-20)', StartHour : 16, EndHour : 20 } } ].
```

Is there anyway to set up Jasmine (as I think Karma has nothing to do with it) to print objects prettier? Just some line breaks and indentation would already be a huge help. Example:

```
Expected spy spy to have been called with [ { 
  currentCareMoment : { 
    ID : 5, 
    Description : 'Late namiddag (16-20)', 
    StartHour : 16, 
    EndHour : 20 
  }, 
  previousCareMoment : { 
    ID : 4, 
    Description : 'Namiddag (14-16)', 
    StartHour : 14, 
    EndHour : 16 
  } 
} ] but actual calls were [ { 
  currentCareMoment : { 
    ID : 6, 
    Description : 'Avond (20-24)', 
    StartHour : 20, 
    EndHour : 24 
  }, 
  previousCareMoment : { 
    ID : 5, 
    Description : 'Late namiddag (16-20)', 
    StartHour : 16, 
    EndHour : 20 
  } 
} ].
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429709/karma-jasmine-tests-highlight-diff-in-terminal But unfortunately, no solution so far

Comment: try use node.js : [util.inspect](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My answer is based on jasmine 2.0.1.

Method 1 is documented in the [jasmine docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html). So it is probably recommended.
Method 2 however is much simpler.

### Method 1: Using a custom matcher

My initial though was to create a custom matcher as described [here](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html). So I copied the toHaveBeenCalledWith matcher from the jasmine source code and modified it so it would pretty print:

```
var matchers = {
  toBeCalledWith: function (util, customEqualityTesters) {
    return {
      compare: function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0),
          actual = args[0],
          expectedArgs = args.slice(1),
          result = { pass: false };

        if (!jasmine.isSpy(actual)) {
          throw new Error('Expected a spy, but got ' + jasmine.JSON.stringify(actual, undefined, 2) + '.');
        }

        if (!actual.calls.any()) {
          result.message = function() {
            return 'Expected spy ' + actual.and.identity() + ' to have been called with ' + JSON.stringify(expectedArgs, undefined, 2) + ' but it was never called.';
          };
          return result;
        }

        if (util.contains(actual.calls.allArgs(), expectedArgs, customEqualityTesters)) {
          result.pass = true;
          result.message = function() {
            return 'Expected spy ' + actual.and.identity() + ' not to have been called with ' + JSON.stringify(expectedArgs, undefined, 2) + ' but it was.';
          };
        } else {
          result.message = function() {
            return 'Expected spy ' + actual.and.identity() + ' to have been called with ' + JSON.stringify(expectedArgs, undefined, 2) + ' but actual calls were ' + JSON.stringify(actual.calls.allArgs(), undefined, 2) + '.';
          };
        }

        return result;
      }
    };
  }
};
```

The test case would then use our new matcher instead:

```
describe('Test', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.addMatchers(matchers);
  });

  it('should print pretty', function() {
    var spy = jasmine.createSpy('spy');
    spy({
      currentCareMoment: {
      ID: 5,
      Description: 'Late namiddag (16-20)',
      StartHour: 16,
      EndHour: 20
    },
    previousCareMoment: {
      ID: 4,
      Description: 'Namiddag (14-16)',
      StartHour: 14,
      EndHour: 16
    }});

    expect(spy).toBeCalledWith({
      currentCareMoment: {
        ID: 6,
        Description: 'Avond (20-24)',
        StartHour: 20,
        EndHour: 24
      },
      previousCareMoment: {
        ID: 5,
        Description: 'Late namiddag (16-20)',
        StartHour: 16,
        EndHour: 20
      }
    });
  });
});
```

### Method 2: Override `jasmine.pp`

However, during implementing this I noticed jasmine uses the function `jasmine.pp` for pretty printing. So I figured I could just override this by adding the following on top of my test file:

```
jasmine.pp = function(obj) {
  return JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 2);
};
```

Comment: Very nice, Remco. I ended up putting this in a separate settings.js file in my test folder. I then include that at the top of the files array in karma.conf.js so it's available to everything.

Answer (score 8):

Since the time that the other answers here were added, a pretty-printing option became available in [karma-jasmine-diff-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jasmine-diff-reporter). I would suggest trying it -- it's very configurable and is working nicely for me in combination with other common test reporters.

A minimal configuration looks like:

```
    reporters: ['jasmine-diff'],

    jasmineDiffReporter: {
        multiline: true,
        pretty: true
    },
```

Comment: I suppose the 'dots' should not be present in the array, if 'jasmine-diff' is. Your current example outputs the report twice.

Answer (score 5):

I found that overriding `jasmine.pp` caused my spec reporters to no longer color-code actual vs. expected diffs.

My solution was to add the below snippet to it's own file, load it into karma.conf, then add the custom matcher (using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) for asserting deep equality) to the config of the reporter that produces color-coded diffs in the console ([karma-jasmine-diff-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jasmine-diff-reporter))

```js
//This will run before all of our specs because it's outside of a describe block
beforeEach(function() {
  var objectMatcher = {
    toEqualObject: function(util, customEqualityTesters) {
      return {
        compare: function(actual, expected) {
          var result = {};
          result.pass = _.isEqual(actual, expected);
          if (result.pass) {
            result.message = "Expected \n" + JSON.stringify(actual, null, 2) + "\n not to equal \n" + JSON.stringify(expected, null, 2) + "\n";
          } else {
            result.message = "Expected \n" + JSON.stringify(actual, null, 2) + "\n to equal \n" + JSON.stringify(expected, null, 2) + "";
          }
          return result;
        }
      };
    }
  };
  jasmine.addMatchers(objectMatcher);
});
```

Now I can get output like this in the console, by calling `expect(foo).toEqualObject(bar)`:

[image: Pretty console output]

Figuring out how to make this work with jasmine spies is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: It's actually a good idea and I'll see if I can implement pretty print right in the reporter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 2)
```

The 3th parameter  is the indentation level

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jasmine custom matcher that removes call arguments from the results that match an Any term in the 'expected'.  Node's `util.inspect` is used to handle circular references and pretty print results.

Output:

```
  custom matcher
    1) should not display arguments corresponding to expected Any arguments

  0 passing (15ms)
  1 failing

  1) custom matcher
       should not display arguments corresponding to expected Any arguments:
     ExpectationFailed: Expected spy underTest to have been called with [
  Any { expectedObject: [Function: Object] },
  { name: 'Bob' },
  { name: 'New York' },
  Any { expectedObject: [Function: Object] }
] but actual calls were [
  [
    '<Hidden due to Any match>',
    { name: 'Joe' },
    { name: 'New York' },
    '<Hidden due to Any match>'
  ]
].
```

toHaveBeenCalledWith.js

```js
'use strict'

import { inspect } from 'util'

export function toHaveBeenCalledWith2 (util, customEqualityTesters) {
  return {
    compare: function () {
      const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)
      const actual = args[0]
      const expectedArgs = args.slice(1)
      const result = { pass: false }

      if (!isSpyLike(actual)) {
        throw new Error('Expected a spy, but got ' + pp(actual) + '.')
      }

      if (!actual.calls.any()) {
        result.message = function () { return 'Expected spy ' + actual.and.identity() + ' to have been called with ' + pp(expectedArgs) + ' but it was never called.'; }
        return result
      }

      if (util.contains(actual.calls.allArgs(), expectedArgs, customEqualityTesters)) {
        result.pass = true
        result.message = function () { return 'Expected spy ' + actual.and.identity() + ' not to have been called with ' + pp(expectedArgs) + ' but it was.' }
      } else {
        const anyIndexes = getIndexesOfJasmineAnyArgs(expectedArgs)
        const actualArgs = stripJasmineAnyArgsFromActual(actual.calls.allArgs(), anyIndexes)
        result.message = function () { return 'Expected spy ' + actual.and.identity() + ' to have been called with ' + pp(expectedArgs) + ' but actual calls were ' + pp(actualArgs) + '.' }
      }

      return result
    },
  }
}

function stripJasmineAnyArgsFromActual (actualArgsList, indexesToIgnore) {
  const strippedArgs = []
  actualArgsList.forEach(args => {
    const stripped = args.map((arg, argIndex) => {
      if (indexesToIgnore.includes(argIndex)) {
        return '<Hidden due to Any match>'
      } else {
        return arg
      }
    })
    strippedArgs.push(stripped)
  })
  return strippedArgs
}

function getIndexesOfJasmineAnyArgs (expectedArgs) {
  const anyIndexes = []
  expectedArgs.forEach((arg, i) => {
    if (arg.constructor.name === 'Any') {
      anyIndexes.push(i)
    }
  })
  return anyIndexes
}

function isSpyLike (possibleSpy) {
  if (!possibleSpy) {
    return false
  }
  return possibleSpy.and && possibleSpy.and.constructor.name === 'SpyStrategy' &&
    possibleSpy.calls && possibleSpy.calls.constructor.name === 'CallTracker'
}

function pp (args) {
  return inspect(args, { depth: 5 })
}
```

Usage:

```
import { toHaveBeenCalledWith2 } from '../matchers/toHaveBeenCalledWith'

describe('custom matcher', function () {

  beforeEach(async function () {
    const matchers = {
      toHaveBeenCalledWith2,
    }
    jasmine.addMatchers(matchers)
  })

  it('should not display arguments corresponding to expected Any arguments', function () {
    const obj = {
      underTest: function (a, person, city, d) { },
    }
    const expectedPerson = {
      name: 'Bob',
    }
    const expectedCity = {
      name: 'New York',
    }

    spyOn(obj, 'underTest')

    obj.underTest({}, { name: 'Joe' }, { name: 'New York' }, {})

    expect(obj.underTest).toHaveBeenCalledWith2(
      jasmine.any(Object),
      expectedPerson,
      expectedCity,
      jasmine.any(Object),
    )
  })
})
```