# karma/jasmine console more detailed test results

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, format, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm using Karma with Jasmine for my javascript unit tests.
Suppose I have a failing test like this:

```
 expect(objectA).toEqual(expectedObjectA);
```

When it fails, I see the two objects dumped on the console and a message telling me the objects are not equal:

[image: console test result]

This is not very helpful because in order to find out why they are not equal, I have to to copy paste the text from the console, split the two objects from that object dump, format them, put them in a diff editor. (Sometimes even that doesn't help because the object are not equal because they have members which are functions).

Is there a way to make jasmine dump to the console the exact name and value of the first property that differs between the two objects?

Is there a way to see the object dump pretty printed? (not really necessary, but it would be nicer than this unreadable dump)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of : [Karma jasmine tests: Highlight diff in terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429709/karma-jasmine-tests-highlight-diff-in-terminal). An [issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/627) has been raised but remains unpursued.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you may need a custom matcher.
Have you had a look at this question ? [Jasmine toEqual for complex objects (mixed with functions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541287/jasmine-toequal-for-complex-objects-mixed-with-functions)